# Is it possible to use Slack RTM with slash commands and dialogs?

Tags: slack-api

RTM seems to be the "new" way to do things (maybe I'm wrong about that).

When adding a slash command, the request URL is required. I just put a random url in there, and when I try to use the slash command, it says `http_client_error`.

This seems like it's trying to post to my "server", which doesn't exist, and, shouldn't need to when using websockets.

Is there no way to react to slash commands using ONLY RTM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, RTM is the "older" approach for event driven apps, while the Events API is the newer way. Nevertheless both have their own advantages and disadvantages, so they are both available today.

Slack commands and Dialogs (now called Modals) do not work with RTM, because they use the HTTP protocol whereas RTM uses Websockets. In other words. If you want to use slash commands or Modals or any other of the interactive features of Slack you need to provide a public HTTP endpoint (or web server), so Slack can send requests to your app.